# Replace all words by javascript except one particular word

Tags: javascript

I want to replace every word including "before" except one particular word including "before" (case-insensitive)

Example: "before" = "after“; except "beforethree"

beforeone beforetwo beforethree beforefour

Result should be:

afterone aftertwo beforethree afterfour

My code is:

```
  <script>
function Replace() {
    var str = document.getElementById("id").innerHTML; 
var res = str.replace(/before/gi, "after");
    document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>
```

Thank you guys very much in advance!

Comment: Use [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to check if the word is **before** but not **beforethree**

Answer (score 4):

You could use a [negative lookahead](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) regex instead:

```
/before(?!three)/gi
```

Answer (score 0):

one option would be to

1. replace `beforethree` with something safe like `%%three`
2. replace `before` with `after`
3. replace `%%` with `before`

I'm sure there are more elegant solutions out there

Answer (score 0):

Modify your replace to be this instead

```
<script>
function Replace() {
    var str = document.getElementById("id").innerHTML; 
    var res = str.replace(/(?!beforethree)before/gi, "after");
    document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>
```